# Insert User and Password in MySQL using code section in inno setup

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

My application uses MySQL Server. Elaborated in inno setup script that does the following:

**In the [code]**

1. Install MySQL Server (Ok)
2. Install MySQL ODBC Connector (Ok)
3. Configure the MySQL Server (Ok)
4. Starts a service MySQL on Windows (Ok)
5. Installs the application (Ok)

**In the [run]**

1. Uses a batch file to enter User and Password in the User table MySQL (Ok)
2. Uses a batch file to create the database application (Ok)
3. Starts the application (Ok)

The script worked fine, however I wanted the items 1 and 2 of section [run] were also carried out in the [code] thus:

**In the [code]**

1. Install MySQL Server (Ok)
2. Install MySQL ODBC Connector (Ok)
3. Configure the MySQL Server (Ok)
4. Starts a service MySQL on Windows (Ok)
5. Uses a batch file to enter User and Password in the User table MySQL (Error)
6. Uses a batch file to create the database application (Error)
7. Installs the application (Ok)

**In the [run]**

1. Starts the application (Ok)

But the second scheme is an error in the inclusion of new user and password and the creation of the database. In the [run] this does not occur.

The code I used in [code] to insert User and Password is as follows:

```
if (CurStep = ssInstall) then
begin WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style: = npbstMarquee; WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption: = 'Starting service MySQL on Windows. This may take a few minutes ... ';
if not Exec (ExpandConstant ('{pf} \ MySQL \ MySQL Server 5.5 \ bin \ mysqld.exe'), 'mysql-u root GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO myusername @ localhost IDENTIFIED BY mypassword WITH GRANT OPTION;' '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
MsgBox ('The MySQL service failed. Code:' + IntToStr (ResultCode) mbInformation, MB_OK);
WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Style: = npbstNormal; WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption: ='';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL client mysql.exe takes SQL commands using the param `-e`

Command should look like this

```
mysql -uroot -e"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION"
```

Also don't forget to set a root password

Comment: Hello Barranka,
Thanks for your reply, but the code did not work. I added the "-e" and "-p", like this:

**'mysql -u root -p -e ' + AddQuotes ('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO myusername@localhost IDENTIFIED BY mypassword WITH GRANT OPTION;')**

I think that would be the correct code below, with the sign ( ' ) among **myusername**, **localhost** and **mypassword**, but inno setup does not accept it because it feels like too many parameters.

'mysql-u root-p-e' + AddQuotes ('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO **'myusername'@'localhost'** IDENTIFIED BY **'mypassword'** WITH GRANT OPTION;')

Comment: If you can't hard-code the values directly within the string, then you need to concatenate the variables with the string constants using the + operator.